# how to convert print output into variable/string with "more than 3 arguments"? (python 3)

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, printing, arguments

Basically I'm trying to take the print output for my code and make it into a variable.  I tried to do this by converting it to a string but it gave me an error saying "TypeError: str() takes at most 3 arguments (6 given)"

my code:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
print(*x, sep='_')  ##gives me the output "1_2_3_4_5"

#problem part:
a = str(*x, sep='_')
print(a)             ##gives error
```

Is there either a way to convert the output to a string despite the "6 argument" thing or some other "str()"-like thing that would work?

Comment: '_'.join(str(x) for x in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert the list of ints to a list of strings using [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map), then use [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to bind them together:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
a = '_'.join(map(str, x))
print(a)  # '1_2_3_4_5'
```

Note: Your code did not work because [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) does some work for you:

> All non-keyword arguments are converted to strings like str() does and written to the stream.

So, print did the string conversion step for you. When you call [`str()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str), it expects only an object to convert to a string, with two optional keyword arguments (`encoding` and `errors`). By calling `str(*x, sep='_')`, you are passing in 5 arguments plus a separator, which is not a valid call.

Answer (score 3):

`*x` supplies much too many arguments to `str()` causing the error, and `sep` isn't an argument of `str()`. `str()` expects one object to be converted, and `*x` gives 5. Try this:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
a = '_'.join(str(i) for i in x)
print(a)
```

This will go through the list and join each element together with an underscore between.

[Try it on IDEOne](https://ideone.com/dLHFqx)

---

You can also use `map(function, sequence)` to shorten the `join()`. The function being applied is `str()` to convert the numbers into string form, and to the `x` list. Here's with `map()`:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
a = '_'.join(map(str, x))
print(a)
```

Comment: is there a difference between '_'.join(str(i) for i in x) and '_'.join(map(str, x)) (the other suggestion) as far as when you can/should use it?

Comment: @zeurosis There's no difference. Map takes in a function to execute (`str()` in this case) and then applies it to all elements of a sequence, `x` in this case. It's just shorthand for what I do - same thing is done behind the scenes.